# Not adding event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-selectors

Not tuch events on input if i use filter "not".
In task i need event blur add to all elements except input in 
div with id ending on "cont".

this not work

```
$("input[id$=inp]").not($("div[id$=cont]").children()).live("blur",someFoo);
```

and this dot work too

```
$("input[id$=inp]").not("div[id$=cont]:children").live("blur",someFoo);
```

Any idea why it hapan ?
How solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** `live` Has to be called directly on the result set.. This works:

```
$("input[id$='inp']:not(div[id$='cont'] input)").live(...)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/29XpW/)

---

The `children` call looks  wrong here. <s>Try:</s>

```
$("input[id$='inp']")
  .not("div[id$='cont'] input")
  .live("blur",someFoo);
```

If you are not adding these elements dynamically, then there is no need to use `.live`:

```
$("input[id$='inp']")
  .not("div[id$='cont'] input")
  .blur(someFoo);
```

Comment: some elements adding dynamically.I try first part it not adding